# What are the alternatives for the expression "The shoes suit you!"?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

> The shoes ____________ [suit you]!

Please, let me know other alternatives when people praise their friends' fine clothes.

Comment: For a friend or a stranger: *I love your shoes!* or *Great shoes!* For close friends only: *Those shoes look good on you!* or *You look great in those shoes!* (Commenting directly on the person's appearance, rather than the clothing itself, can be tricky, so save it for people who won't misunderstand.)

Comment: @1006a How kind you are! I'm loving it! I appreciate it for the additional description of situation!

Comment: @1006a — I quote: "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments."

Comment: It would help us include answers that may be appropriate to you if you ammended your question to indicate your country of residence, age group and social class.

Answer (score 3):

A more old-fashioned (and perhaps more elegant) construction uses ‘become’ rather than ‘suit’.

> **become** 2. *[with object]* (of clothing) look good on or suit (someone)
>
> ‘mourning regalia became her’

[Oxford Dictionary online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/become)

Comment: While it is "technically" correct, the term is, as you note, old-fashioned. I'd even go as far as to say it's pretentious, and if you do say it to someone nowadays, you're either going to: 1) confuse them because they won't know what you meant, and then you'll be stuck in the awkward situation of having to explain yourself or restate what you meant, or 2) distance them from yourself because they'll see you as someone who feels compelled to use archaic words to sound "smart", especially if you're saying this in an informal, casual setting with your friends.

Comment: @AleksandrH — Depends on the company you keep. My friends would appreciate it. If the poster is not familiar with the usage of the word he shouldn't employ it (as for any word). But the aim of this SE is to accumulate a set of answers to questions, so this contributes.

Comment: @AleksandrH Thanks guy! Could you give me another phrase? 

Comment: @David Your answer would help me out ! 

Comment: @David Touché, I guess it depends.

Answer (score 3):

The shoes ***fit you to a T***!

yourdictionary.com:

> [**to-a-t**](http://www.yourdictionary.com/to-a-t)
>
> *Adverb* (not comparable)
>
> (idiomatic) Precisely; exactly; perfectly; with great attention to
>   detail.
>
> The colors of your suit fit you to a T.